Unable to externalize pgfplots with lualatex
I am working on a long document with a lot of PGF plots and want to externalize the plots to reduce the execution time.
As far as I understood the docs, see here and here, externalization requires the following steps:

load externalization library (with \usepgfplotslibrary{external} in the document)
enable/activate externalization (with \tikzexternalize in the document)
enable/allow shell-escape (with option --shell-escape when calling lualatex)

However, I get the following error message when executing compilation:

===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex -halt-on-error -inter action=batchmode -jobname "externalize_test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{
externalize_test}\input{externalize_test}"' ========
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -halt-on-error
-interact ion=batchmode -jobname "externalize_test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{ext ernalize_test}\input{externalize_test}"'
did NOT result in a usable output file  'externalize_test-figure0'
(expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please ver ify that you have
enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell- escape'.
Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe
the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in
'externalize_test-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to
typeset the picture.

Some Internet research showed that this problem seems to be quite common and is usually related to a faulty editor configuration. However, I do not call lualatex from within my editor, but directly from the terminal:
lualatex externalize_test.tex --shell-escape

As I explicitly set the --shell-escape option, I would assume that shell-escape should be enabled and the aforementioned prerequisites are fulfilled.
The log file externalize_test-figure0.log mentioned in the error message is not generated, only a externalize_test-figure0.md5 (later used to check for changes on the figure and re-trigger externalization) is created.
I also read other questions (see list below), but nothing hinted me into an obvious reason for the issue.
What am I missing here?

MWE:
% filename: externalize_test.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot+{x^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


System Information:

lualatex: LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
shellesc: shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
pgfplots: pgfplots.sty    2021/05/15 v1.18.1 Data Visualization (1.18.1)
editor: VS Code 1.86.2
OS: macOS Monterey 12.6.2 (on Apple Silicon)


Already read:

https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-external
https://tikz.dev/library-external
https://man.archlinux.org/man/luatex.1.en#shell
Does the lualatex shell enable behavior differ from pdflatex on purpose?
Cannot run tikz externalize with lualatex but it used to work
Question regarding pgfplots externalize
https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=18746 (in German)
How to get the pgfplots external tutorial to work in TeXnicCenter?
About use of \usepgfplotslibrary{external} and \tikzexternalize in Overleaf
Problem combining tikzexternalize, tikzscale and external graphics


Try with lualatex --shell-escape filename

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Thanks, it's working now. Clearly, the infix vs. postfix notation problem discussed here. Even though I had read this question, I missed it in my command. When you mentioned the correct order of command, option and filename, I immediately noticed the error. Thanks a lot.

You're welcome!
